# Why netstat -p doesn't show PID of established connections?

Tags: netstat

I have some REST service which is listening on tcp/8051
I'm querying this service with `curl` in infinite loop from the same host:
`while true; do curl --header "Authorization: Bearer NDkwMjM3NzEtN2U2NS00ZDVkLThhYzItOThmZTliODljNWJj" -k "https://x.x.7.131:8051/status/service"; done`

In other window i'm checking connections with `netstat` (under root):
`while true; do netstat -antep |grep :8051 && echo ""; done`

Output of `netstat`

```
tcp        0      0 x.x.7.131:8051          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      508        1150035894 48623/java
tcp        0      0 x.x.7.131:8051          x.x.7.131:47858         ESTABLISHED 508        1150589130 -
tcp        0      0 x.x.7.131:8051          x.x.7.131:47860         ESTABLISHED 508        1150589177 -

tcp        0      0 x.x.7.131:8051          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      508        1150035894 48623/java
tcp        0      0 x.x.7.131:8051          x.x.7.131:47898         ESTABLISHED 508        1150590086 -
tcp        0      0 x.x.7.131:8051          x.x.7.131:47905         ESTABLISHED 508        1150590252 -
tcp        0      0 x.x.7.131:8051          x.x.7.131:47907         ESTABLISHED 508        1150590301 -
tcp        0      0 x.x.7.131:47911         x.x.7.131:8051          ESTABLISHED 508        1150590389 -

tcp        0      0 x.x.7.131:8051          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      508        1150035894 48623/java
tcp        0      0 x.x.7.131:47925         x.x.7.131:8051          ESTABLISHED 508        1150590821 -
tcp        0      0 x.x.7.131:47933         x.x.7.131:8051          ESTABLISHED 508        1150590965 -

tcp        0      0 x.x.7.131:8051          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      508        1150035894 48623/java
tcp        0      0 x.x.7.131:47976         x.x.7.131:8051          ESTABLISHED 508        1150591963 -
tcp        0      0 x.x.7.131:47977         x.x.7.131:8051          ESTABLISHED 508        1150591986 -
tcp        0      0 x.x.7.131:47991         x.x.7.131:8051          ESTABLISHED 508        1150592211 -
```

Why i don't see PIDs?
OS: RHEL6.6